# SSH command for find and replace

Tags: ssh, command

I am wanting to change the username and password in all my config files

What would the command be in SSH to find

```
$txpcfg['user'] = 'EXAMPLE-1';
```

And change it across my server to:

```
$txpcfg['user'] = 'EXAMPLE-2';
```

Comment: `ssh` is a connection tool, not a shell.

Answer (score 0):

[sed](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sed) can be used with the `-i` flag to do in-line replacement.

Something like:

```
find /path/to/workingDir -name *.config -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i 's/\$txpcfg\[\'user\'\]\ = \'$oldUser\';/\$txpcfg\[\'user\'\]\ \=\ \'$newUser\';/g'
```

That regex / search pattern can probably be cleaned up.